# Why is password_verify returning false when it's true

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$server_host = "mysql-omarsdajani.alwaysdata.net";
$server_username =  "usertestsest";
$server_password = "testtest";
$server_dbName = "omarsdajani_hustlehut";

$player_email = $_POST ["emailPost"];
$player_password = $_POST ["passwordPost"];

$conn = mysqli_connect ($server_host, $server_username, $server_password, $server_dbName);

if (!$conn) {
    echo ("Could not connect to the server.");
}

$findPlayer = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '$player_email'");

if (mysqli_num_rows ($findPlayer) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($findPlayer)) {
        if (password_verify ($player_password, $row['Password'])) {
            echo ("Signed in");
            echo ("|ID:" . $row['ID'] . "|Email:" . $row['Email'] . "|Username:" . $row['Username'] . "|Name:" . $row['Name'] . "|Date Registered:" 
            . $row['Date_Registered'] . "|Goal:" . $row['Goal'] . "|System:" . $row ['System'] . "|Starting BFP:" . $row ['Starting_BFP'] . 
            "|Starting Weight:" . $row ['Starting_Weight'] . "|Cal Goal:" . $row ['Cal_Goal'] . "|Carb Goal:" . $row ['Carb_Goal'] . 
            "|Protein Goal:" . $row ['Protein_Goal'] . "|Fat Goal:" . $row ['Fat_Goal'] . "|Current Carbs:" . $row ['Current_Carb'] . 
            "|Current Protein:" . $row ['Current_Protein'] . "|Current Fat:" . $row ['Current_Fat'] . "|Current Cals:" . $row ['Current_Cals'] 
            . "|Current BFP:" . $row ['Current_BFP'] . "|Current Weight:" . $row ['Current_Weight']);
        } else {
            echo ("Incorrect password");
        }
    }
} else {
    echo ("Incorrect email");
}
```

Above is my PHP Login script, the password won't verify. I echoed $player_password and the password input from the POST is correct. The issue is the passwords won't verify. And in my DB the column length for the Password column is 600 characters. I honestly do not know what is wrong here.

Comment: Make the column length for the password `CHAR(60)`

Comment: Try a bit more debugging. Instead of echoing the password, try echoing the hash from the database, together with the hash from `password_hash($player_password,<your algo>);` and see if they are exactly the same. I need to point out that your login script is vulnerable to SQL-injection, and therefore not very secure.

Comment: @SaadSuri  it doesn't matter. OP has already defined an appropriate length

Comment: Show us how you used `password_hash()`

Comment: @Akintunde - this is how I used it.  $encrypted_password = password_hash ($player_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I have already tried that. They are the exact same. And how should I go about making it more secure?

Comment: If they are the same then `password_verify()` should return `TRUE`. Did you get a row? This code is not complex, you should be able to get it to work. You could have googled the term "SQL-injection", but here's a link: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/prevent-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-in-php-applications